# Keep UICollectionViewCell centered after Zooming with UIPinchGestureRecognizer

Tags: uicollectionview, uigesturerecognizer, uicollectionviewcell, cgaffinetransform, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I'm having this issue. I change the scale and as well the transition of the view of a `UICollectionViewCell`, for doing zoom in the position of my fingers do the UIPinchGesture. But after that, the position of the view changes and the view go off the screen and its bounds. I want that the Gesture View get back to its correct position.

This is what is happening:

[image]

I have tried to assign a `CGAffineTransformIdentity` to the view if the center of the cell changes, but after the `Scale` and the `Translate`, its center always changes, so its `frame` as well.

The code in `UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded`:

```
    if ([gesture state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded){

       //Get the Cell that is getting zoomed
       CGPoint initialPinchPoint = [gesture locationInView:self.collectionView];

       NSIndexPath* pinchedCellPath = [self.collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:initialPinchPoint];

       SBQPhotosDetailCollectionViewCell *cell=[[SBQPhotosDetailCollectionViewCell alloc] init];

       cell=(SBQPhotosDetailCollectionViewCell *)[self.collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:pinchedCellPath];

       //Check ifs frame with the gesture of the Pinch
       if ((cell.frame.origin.x != [gesture view].frame.origin.x) || (cell.frame.origin.y  != [gesture view].frame.origin.y)){

          [gesture view].transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
       }
    }
```

I would like to apply the `CGAffineTransformIdentity` only if the view of the `Gesture` change its `center`, `position`, but not if the `view` got `zoomed`.

Thanks

Comment: I think what you are asking is not very clear, you could provide some screenshots or further explanation.